# AngularJS Registering Click Event to Multiple Elements like JQuery Style

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Is there angular style to listen to clicks on elements without using ng-click.

In JQuery we can do it this:

```
$("div").on("click",function);
$("div").click(function);
```

This helps in registering click dynamically.

What is the Angular way to do this?

Comment: I think you should not do that, you should keep the controller clean from UI dependency, take a look [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background) as reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jqLite:

```
angular.element(e).on('click', function($event) {...});
```